# Not able to provide access to Azure Data Lake Store files from HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure

I was trying to create a new HDInsight cluster and wanted to connect to already created Azure Data Lake Store account(ADLS). I have selected HDI V3.5 as the cluster type for HDInsight. I was able to select my Data Lake as my storage, but when I created SPI account and when I tried to provide ADLS access to that account I don't see my ADLS root folder. Do I need to provide any additional permissions for my ADLS in order to appear in mange ADLS access blade? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a root folder in the ADLS account before creating the HDI cluster so that the root path is defined while creating the cluster.

For eg., create a root folder /clusters and the root path in your cluster would be /clusters/yourclustername. And also make sure you give access to the root folder in "Manage Access" blade while creating a HDI cluster.

Refer this for more info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-hdinsight-hadoop-use-portal

Answer (score 0):

ADLA file system has separate UNIX like access control called ACL (Access control list). You(login email id) should have ACL access at root folder to access the same in HDInsight cluster.